# my html script tags aren't linking to my external javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to write a small rock, paper scissors machine but there seems to be something wrong with the script tags in my HTML.

it works when I put the script between the script tags but I've been told that doing so is confusing.`

```js
var selector = document.getElementById('selectors');
var title = document.getElementById('title');

var userInput = '';

var choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
var computerChoice = '';

var outcome = '';

function getUserInput() {
  if (class = 'rock') {
    userInput = 'rock';
    return userInput;
  } else if (class = 'paper') {
    userInput = 'paper';
    return userInput;
  } else if (class = 'scissors') {
    userInput = 'scissors';
    return userInput;
  }
}

function change() {
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = 'it has worked'
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>scissors, paper, rock engine</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./rockPaperScissors.js"></script>
</head>
```

**strong text**`

Comment: `class` is a reserved word. You can't use it as a variable

Comment: Have you tried using `src = "/rockPaperScissors.js"`

Comment: have you tried moving your ```script tags``` before closing body tag?

Comment: `=` is assignment `==` is truthy comparison and `===` is exact comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If all files are in same folder then try by removing the dot and slash

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="rockPaperScissors.js"></script>
```

Comment: please share the folder structure

Answer (score 0):

Or add two dots before / if your script is located one level up.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../rockPaperScissors.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that it didn't work because of the getUserInput function

it is working now

Answer (score 0):

In function getUserInput, you have two errors,
First, you can't use the class as it's a reserved keyword.
Second, I hope you are trying to compare the class name with the string, you need to place === or!== to check.

To check if the file loaded successfully or not...
Right click on your site and choose Inspect. It will open a new window of chrome developer tools. In that go to network and refresh(F5). It shows every document, image and supporting files required for that web page. and If you click on any file, it gives the details about headers, preview, response and timing details of that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi first of all kindly solve this error in your code i.e.

```
function getUserInput() {
if (class == 'rock') {           //here = should be ==
 userInput = 'rock';
 return userInput;
} else if (class == 'paper') {   //here = should be ==
 userInput = 'paper';
 return userInput;
} else if (class == 'scissors') {    //here = should be ==
 userInput = 'scissors';
 return userInput;
}
}
```

as you are comparing the values in condition and as for script tag simply specify in src if have file in same directory simply use file name e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

Comment: also `class` is a javascript reserved word. Can't be used as variable

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to include an example of what your code might end up looking like.

```js
var doc, bod, M, I, S, Q, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){ // load wrapper
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
M = function(tag){ // make element
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){ // document.getElementById(id)
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){ // .querySelector
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){ // .querySelectorAll
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
aC = function(element, className, text){ // addClass
  var s = element.className.split(/\s+/), n = s.indexOf(className);
  if(n === -1){
    s.push(className); element.className = s.join(' ');
  }
  if(text !== undefined){
    if(element.value === undefined){
      element.innerHTML = text;
    }
    else{
      element.value = text;
    }
  }
  return function(className, text){
    return aC(element, className, text);
  }
}
rC = function(element, className, text){ // remove class
  var s = element.className.split(/\s+/), n = s.indexOf(className);
  if(n !== -1){
    s.splice(n, 1); element.className = s.join(' ');
  }
  if(text !== undefined){
    if(typeof element.innerHTML === 'undefined'){
      element.value = text;
    }
    else{
      element.innerHTML = text;
    }
  }
  return function(className, text){
    return rC(element, className, text);
  }
}
tC = function(element, className, onText, offText){ // toggle class
  var s = element.className.split(/\s+/), n = s.indexOf(className);
  if(n === -1){
    s.push(className); element.className = s.join(' ');
    if(onText !== undefined){
      if(element.value === undefined){
        element.innerHTML = onText;
      }
      else{
        element.value = onText;
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    s.splice(n, 1); element.className = s.join(' ');
    if(offText !== undefined){
      if(element.value === undefined){
        element.innerHTML = offText;
      }
      else{
        element.value = offText;
      }
    }
  }
  return function(className, onText, offText){
    return tC(element, className, onText, offText);
  }
}
var players = I('players'), playerCount = +players.value, comp = I('computer'), player2 = I('player2'), res = I('res'), play1, play2;
function randPSR(){
  var a = ['paper', 'scissors', 'rock'];
  return a[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
}
function psr(p1, p2){
  var yp, op;
  if(p1 === p2){
    return "It's a tie. Play again!";
  }
  if(playerCount === 1){
    yp = 'You Win'; op = 'Computer';
  }
  else{
    yp = 'Player 1 Wins'; op = 'Player 2';
  }
  switch(p1){
    case 'paper':
      switch(p2){
        case 'scissors':
          return op+' Wins - Scissors Beats Paper';
        case 'rock':
          return yp+' - Paper Beats Rock';
      }
      break;
    case 'scissors':
      switch(p2){
        case 'paper':
          return yp+' - Scissors Beats Paper';
        case 'rock':
          return op+' Wins - Rock Beats Scissors';
      }
      break;
    case 'rock':
      switch(p2){
        case 'paper':
          return op+' Wins - Paper Beats Rock';
        case 'scissors':
          return yp+' - Rock Beats Scissors';
      }
      break;
  }
}
function paperScissorsRock(){
  aC(comp, 'hide'); comp.innerHTML = res.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i=0,p1buttons=Q('#player1>input[type=button]'),p2buttons=Q('#player2>input[type=button]'),l=p1buttons.length; i<l; i++){
    p1buttons[i].onclick = function(){
      play1 = this.value;
      if(playerCount === 1){
        play2 = randPSR(); comp.innerHTML = 'Computer Picks "'+play2+'"'; rC(comp, 'hide');
      }
      else if(!play1 || !play2){
        res.innerHTML = '';
      }
      if(play1 && play2){
        res.innerHTML = psr(play1, play2); play1 = play2 = false;
      }
    }
    p2buttons[i].onclick = function(){
      play2 = this.value;
      if(!play1 || !play2)res.innerHTML = '';
      if(play1 && play2){
        res.innerHTML = psr(play1, play2); play1 = play2 = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
paperScissorsRock();
players.addEventListener('change', function(){
  aC(comp, 'hide'); comp.innerHTML = res.innerHTML = ''; play1 = play2 = false; playerCount = +this.value;
  playerCount === 1 ? aC(player2, 'hide') : rC(player2, 'hide');
});
}); // end load wrapper
```

```css
*{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#aaa; color:#000; overflow-x:hidden; 
}
body{
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
select,#computer{
  border:0; margin-bottom:15px;
}
select,input{
  cursor:pointer;
}
label,select,input[type=button]{
  font:22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; padding:5px 10px; border-radius:5px;
}
input[type=button]{
  background:#ccc; border:3px solid #000; margin-bottom:15px;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Same Page Paper Scissors Rock</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <label id='players_label' for='players'>Players</label>
    <select name='players' id='players'>
      <option value='1' selected='selected'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
    <div class='hide' id='computer'></div>
    <div id='player1'>
      <input type='button' value='paper' />
      <input type='button' value='scissors' />
      <input type='button' value='rock' />
    </div>
    <div class='hide' id='player2'>
      <input type='button' value='paper' />
      <input type='button' value='scissors' />
      <input type='button' value='rock' />
    </div>
    <div id='res'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```